Razor Component Not Recognizing .razor.css File in Blazor Project
I'm facing an issue with my Blazor project (using .Net 8) where the .razor.css file is not being recognized by the corresponding Razor component.
Issue: The styles defined in MyComponent.razor.css are not being applied to MyComponent.razor. I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:
1.Ensured that the .razor.css file has the same name as the .razor file and is in the same folder.
2.Cleaned and rebuilt the solution in Visual Studio.
3.Verified the inclusion of the styles in index.html by adding:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MyComponent.razor.css" /> 
Despite these efforts, the styles are still not being applied. Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.
MyComponentBase.razor :
@inherits MyComponentBase

@foreach (var item in Products) {
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
        <a href="/ProductDetails/@item.Id">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="img-thumbnail img-hover" src="@item.ImageURL">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-3">
                        @item.Name
                    </h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <b>@item.Price.ToString("C")</b>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
}

MyComponentBase.razor.css :
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

    a:hover .card {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

.card {
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a:hover .img-hover {
    transform: scale(1.07);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.img-hover {
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0 You are not doing this  in Blazor.

That is the point of css isolation, to get rid of the link. Razor is doing this for us.

Have you tried clearing the browser cache? Razor adds tags to every element of a component (looks something like b-....) and adds the same tags as a rule to the generated CSS file. They can get out of sync

use the ASSEMBLY NAME not the component name. All the isolotated css ends up in this one file consolidated. In fact the .css file you are editing is not even output.

CSS isolation helps to scopes CSS to specific Razor component and avoid collisions with other components or libraries. When it doesn't work, we need to check first in browser whether the request for projectname.style.css is successful or not. If it's correct, then check the response of this request to see whether the content contained the scoped css. If it also contained the css, maybe you are trying to apply the style to child component?  Normally speaking, there won't be such issue occur, so that may I know the project struction?

And maybe you disabled CSS isolation? <ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>

According to your description "Verified the inclusion of the styles in index.html by adding: ", we could know that you are working on a blazor web assembly application. And you are creating Component.razor.css so that I'm afraid you are trying to scope CSS to corresponding Razor components and this is called CSS isolation as we know.
To enable CSS isolation in our blazor application, we don't need to add <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyComponent.razor.css" />, we just need to make sure <link href="{ProjectName}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> is added. And the project created by template will have this link by default.
In the meantime, even if we added this extra line <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyComponent.razor.css" />, it won't affect the app except an 404 error. Please see my test result below. ProjectName.style.css is loaded and the css we defined in .raozr.css just over there and the request for Component.razor.css returned 404. The hover style is applied successfully too. By the way, the style name is in format b-{string}, if you can't see it, there shall be something wrong within the build progress as CSS isolation occurs at build time.


